# My code uses `ClebschGordan` but `Mathematica` is using `ThreeJSymbol`

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions, physics

I'm using a function that calculate CG coefficients with the function
`ClebschGordan` but instead, I've got the following error because Mathematica is using `ThreeJSymbol`:

`ClebschGordan::phy: "ThreeJSymbol[{1/2,1/2},{0,0},{1/2,1/2}] is not physical.`

I know that this 3JSymbols isn't physical but is a valid value for a CG coefficient:

`ClebschGordan[{1/2, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}]`

gives `1` as result.

Edit: Here is all the code and the actual code that I'm running.

```
GeneradorQs[M_] := 
 Module[{l = Length[M], q, i}, q = {M[[l]] + M[[l - 1]]};
  Table[AppendTo[q, q[[i]] + M[[l - (i + 1)]]], {i, 1, l - 3}];
  q]

RangoAngular[j_] := Table[m, {m, -j, j}]

QVD[k_, q_] := 
 Module[{i, total = 0}, 
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[k], i++, 
   If[MemberQ[RangoAngular[k[[i]]], q[[i]]], total += 1]];
  If[total == Length[k], True, False]]

Mexico[k_, q_, M_, j_, m_] := 
 Module[{l = Length[M], prod = 0, i}, 
  prod = ClebschGordan[{1/2, M[[l - 1]]}, {1/2, M[[l]]}, {k[[1]], 
     q[[1]]}];
  For[i = 1, i <= l - 3, i++, 
   prod *= ClebschGordan[{1/2, M[[l - i]]}, {k[[i]], 
      q[[i]]}, {k[[i + 1]], q[[i + 1]]}]];
  prod *= 
   ClebschGordan[{1/2, M[[1]]}, {k[[l - 2]], q[[l - 2]]}, {j, m}]]

Lapiz[K_, M_, j_, m_] := 
 If[Total[M] == m && 
   QVD[K, GeneradorQs[M]], {Mexico[K, GeneradorQs[M], M, j, m], 
   M}, {0, M}]
```

And I'm calling the function `Lapiz` with:

```
Lapiz[{0, 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2)}, 0, 0]
```

Edit${}^2$:

The snippet:

`For[i = 1, i <= l - 3, i++, 
   prod *= ClebschGordan[{1/2, M[[l - i]]}, {k[[i]], 
      q[[i]]}, {k[[i + 1]], q[[i + 1]]}]];`

have to be changed for

`For[i = 1, i <= l - 3, i++, 
   prod *= ClebschGordan[{1/2, M[[l - (i-1)]]}, {k[[i]], 
      q[[i]]}, {k[[i + 1]], q[[i + 1]]}]];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably entered

```
ClebschGordan[{1/2,1/2},{0,0},{1/2,-1/2}]
```

and got the warning message. This happens when you use angular-momentum quantum numbers that don't satisfy the conservation laws. In this case, the rule $m_1+m_2=m$ is not met, see the documentation for [`ClebschGordan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClebschGordan.html). However, *Mathematica* still produces the correct result, i.e., `0`. This just says that the product state with individual angular-momentum `z` momenta $0$ and $\frac12$ does not occur in the total-angular-momentum state with `z` angular momentum $-\frac12$.

All you have to do is turn off the warning message, and everything will be fine:

```
Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
```

See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45022/245).

In your function `Mexico`, you do indeed call `ClebschGordan[{1/2,1/2},{0,0},{1/2,-1/2}]` as I suspected. This is easily confirmed by modifying the definition of `Mexico` by replacing `ClebschGordan` by `ClebschGordan1` to see what arguments the functions are getting.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't the case. The message that Mathematica shows me says that I'm doing: `ClebschGordan[{1/2, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}]`. I'm thinking that the problem is somewhere else because, I've written `CG[a_, b_, c_] := 
 If[a == {1/2, 1/2} && c == {1/2, 1/2} && b == {0, 0}, 1, 
  ClebschGordan[a, b, c]]` but still giving me the same error.

Comment: I don't understand. You'd have to post the actual input that gives rise to the warning. I get the warning you quote when I input the values I stated above. What happens if you type `ClebschGordan[{1/2,1/2},{0,0},{1/2,1/2}]`? You don't get any warning, or do you? If you do, what version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I don't get any warning, just `1`. But when ClebschGordan is called with the same arguments **inside** my functions* gives me the error that I put in the post. My functions is ```

Comment: As I said, you would have to post valid code to reproduce the problem before I can say anything else.

Comment: I'm posting all the code...

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as I thought. See my updated answer.

Comment: So, the message that gives Mathematica doesn't correspond with the actual arguments that is receiving?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding something. Probably something in your  loops is wrong, but I can't guess what their purpose is. `CG` invokes `ThreeJSymbol` but that has the rule that the m indices add up to *minus* the total `m`. The error corresponds exactly to the incorrect invocation I mentioned, and everything is the way it should be. The warning does deserve to be turned off *when you know what you're doing*. In your case, the warning probably points to a separate error that is specific to your loop.

Comment: @David, it should be noted that *Mathematica* is using a very general definition for all of `ClebschGordan[]`, `ThreeJSymbol[]`, and `SixJSymbol[]` that will work for arguments not necessarily corresponding to the physically sensible ones, but is helpful enough to warn you if you are doing so. (If you need a refresher on the restrictions, see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ClebschGordan/02/).)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I fond that the `For` in `Mexico` have the indices in an incorrect way.